# Deploying multiple contracts

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-deployment

Let's assume I have multiple contracts defined, say 1 lib, 1 interface, A contract and B contract and B is A and finally, B uses both, the lib and the interface specified.

The question is, should I pack them up into one file, compile and simply deploy **only** B like below?

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider'); 
const Web3 = require('web3'); 

const {interface, bytecode} = require('./compile');
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
    'mnemonic',
    'https://link to infura'
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);
const deploy = async () => {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    const result = await web3.eth.Contract(JASON.parse('interface'))
        .deploy({data: bytecode})
        .send({gas: '1000000', from: accounts[0]});

    console.log(result.options.address); 
};

deploy();
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Hey, when you're supplying code, it's best to indent it with 4 spaces to block quote (you can also select and just Command-K or Control-K to indent the selected lines).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, everything you described except the Lib are compiler-only concerns. You deploy the Lib, bind B to the Lib at the Lib address and deploy B.

Comment: That makes sense. However how to bind the library to B? Where to include the information in B to direct it to the lib?

Comment: If you have the source code for the library, there is an easier way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299286/how-connect-library-to-smart-contract-from-external-resources